# Is it possible to implement left outer join in Flink's CoGroupedStreams.coGroup()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In reference to post - [Flink co group outer join fails with High Backpressure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64258058/flink-co-group-outer-join-fails-with-high-backpressure/75439030#75439030)

would "CalculateCoGroupFunction.coGroup" method implementation support left outer join on multiple streams (in my use case I have three stream sources that would need to be joined). I would appreciate if you could share any examples you may have on left outer joins using coGroup().

Thanks in advance!

```
DataStream<Message> pStream =
    stream1
    .coGroup(stream2)
    .where(obj -> obj.getid())
    .equalTo(ev -> ev.getid())
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(Constants.VALIDTY_WINDOW_MIN)))
        .evictor(TimeEvictor.of(Time.minutes(Constants.VALIDTY_WINDOW_MIN)))
    .apply(new CalculateCoGroupFunction());
```

Looking for a working example of coGroup implementation for left outer joins on multiple streams ( > 3 streams)

Comment: So you have one stream that is the "right side", and > 1 stream for the left side?

Comment: Hi @kkrugler, thanks for the question.

left side = 1 stream, and on the right side > 1 stream. to give an analogy in sql terms that would look like ( where a1 is stream on the left side, and b1 and c1 are two streams on the right). Essentially keep all records from a1 stream

SELECT 
  *
FROM a1
LEFT JOIN b1 ON foo...
LEFT JOIN c1 ON bar...

Answer (score 0):

You can do a union on stream 2 and 3 (right side), then coGroup on stream1. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
stream1
    .coGroup(stream2.union(stream3))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the right side streams are the same type (contain records of the same class) then you can do a union as per @Sean L's answer above.

If not, then the standard approach is to create a class (something like Flink's `Either`) that can contain one of N different records, each with a different type. You first run each right side stream through a map function that creates this `Either` record, then you can union them all together before doing the `coGroup()`. You'll typically have a `.getKey()` method in this `Either` class that knows how to extract the appropriate field from the record that is in the wrapper class.